# How to retain google auth user data between Jetpack Compose screens?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

Specifically, how do I transfer that user data to a different screen with the generic Jetpack Compose navigation?

I could just transfer the email and password, re-sign in, but this seems like a pretty terrible way to do it (and impossible because firebase will start to deny after a certain amount of logins in a short period of time).

I would pass the auth object itself, but navigation only allows strings to be passed.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: That kind of information should live in some kind of Controller or Service. It shouldn't live only in your UI.

Answer (score 2):

If all screens are part of the same app, the Firebase Authentication SDK already maintains the signed in user's state for you.

You can just read the current user as shown in this code snippet from the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#kotlin+ktx):

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

Comment: [The code. It's always null.](https://imgur.com/a/g9pvTIi) I'm guessing it has something to do with it signing in within the composable, does that data get erased after going to the next composable/screen?

Comment: The Firebase SDK automatically persist the signed in user and their credentials, so that it can restore them when the app restarts. If you're seeing a different behavior, edit your question to include the [minimal code that any of us can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's useful). Also check out https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example